Is there an opposite of "kiss of death"?
When disreputable person A supports person B, it may be unhelpful for reputation of person B. Sometimes it is called a "kiss of death". What is the name of the situation when disreputable person A publicly rebukes person B and as a result we sympathize more with person B?

The title question allows different  answers than 'What is the name of the situation when disreputable person A publicly rebukes person B and as a result we sympathize more with person B?'

Steven Hawking asked What is it that breathes fire into the equations and makes a universe for them to describe? That sounds to me like the antonym of delivering the kiss of death.

Not so much in America, which primarily loves winners, but in Britain we tend to root for the underdog - so if A and B are both scumbags, but A publicly trashes B, that makes B an extreme underdog, thus possibly gaining our support.

Have you considered "kiss of life"?

This is called "having all the right enemies". It's an important effect in politics. There are situations where every time a radical opponent pays money to spew nonsense out your tv, your polling numbers go up. Hillary Clinton is probably the best example. She had the best enemies saying the dumbest things which boosted her political credibility enormously - all on their dime.
Unfortunately, there is both a book and a song with this title, making usage searches a nightmare.
But here's one where they tried to capture Hillary's magical enemies and pawn them off on poor Bernie. But it didn't really stick.
https://www.truthdig.com/articles/bernie-sanders-has-all-the-right-enemies/

There are a lot of similar phrases in use, e.g. there's a biography of Tucker Carlson called Hated by All the Right People. But anything in this ballpark is good.

Hillary Clinton "had the best enemies saying the dumbest things". You don't think that's because mainstream media were almost unanimously behind her, and thus went out of their way to publicize the dumbest things her dumbest opponents said, so even the dumbest of the dumb "deplorable" voters might shift their opinions in her favour? Just sayin'

@FumbleFingers - sure, but they made it sooo easy.

Thanks. I accepted this answer because I saw an op-ed on Al Jazeera website titled "Greta Thunberg – still making all the right enemies". So the phrase is indeed in circulation.

To turn someone into a martyr is often used to describe overemphasising [this must be a value judgement] a person's genuine hardships and struggles in life to encourage public sympathy and support.

Letter: Don’t turn Trump into [a] martyr
Donald Trump’s legal problems seem endless....
Then there are the criminal cases.
So what does all this mean?
It means we are in serious danger of making Donald Trump into a
martyr. He may, in the minds of many, join such true martyrs as
Lincoln, Gandhi, Joan of Arc, and of course, Jesus. This would
enormously, and dangerously, increase his chance of once again being
elected president.

[Bruce L. Melkonian, Vancouver; 'Columbian'
Published: March 7, 2024]

Well, sometimes it can work. I remember when Trump fired an ex-FBI boss from some minor function, there was an op somewhere with a headline "Brennan is a hack. He doesn't deserve to be martyred by Trump.". (A bit twisted logic) . But you need to really suffer for martyrdom.

'Disreputable person A publicly rebukes person B' is fun for B?

I'm not sure there is an umbrella word or idiom, but there are some specific cases:
If you were originally unsympathetic or antipathetic towards B, but now feel differently because of the actions of A, you could say or reason that:
The enemy of my enemy is my friend (proverb)

An ancient proverb which suggests that two parties can or should work
together against a common enemy.
Wikipedia

If A  diminishes or picks on an already weaker B, you may support B so you can
root/cheer for the underdog (phrase)

underdog (n.)
1: A loser or predicted loser in a struggle or contest
2: A victim of injustice or persecution
M-W


One of the reasons people root for the underdog is because of the
burst of additional pleasure we feel when the underdog wins.
Monica
C. Parker; The Power of Wonder (2023)

A's behavior may cause you to support B purely or mainly with the hope of feeling Schadenfreude if B prevails over A.
Schadenfreude (n)

Malicious enjoyment of the misfortunes of others
[OED online]


Maybe saying "enemy of my enemy is my friend" is the best solution. Probably there's no better idiom for that. Many people in fact don't realise how little an opinion of somebody generally detested is worth. These guys still share their reprimands and endorsements and everybody acts as if this was a good idea.

Haha I should have read your answer before commenting! I agree that "underdog" is a relevant term here

@GerardDomek: You can't take any of this too far. Most people rarely or never change their mind about public figures (politicians, media stars, etc.) so it doesn't make any difference what anyone says about anyone else. Mostly, people just ignore anything they don't already agree with.

"The kiss of life" would be a nice opposite of what you are talking about. What you posted was kind of simple in terms of English.
It is a phrase that is commonly used metaphorically = to revitalise:

The English victory in 1966 seemed to give the domestic game the kiss
of life — for the short term at least.  The People’s Game: The History
of Football Revisited James Walvin


Now the pictures are spread on the VF light box in the office. I feel they are gold dust. The gaiety of this cover will be not just the Reagan kiss, but the kiss of life for Vanity Fair. The Vanity Fair Diaries: 1983—1992: Tina Brown 2017


Do you have an example of this use of "kiss of life"?

"Kiss of life" is often used as a synonym for mouth-to-mouth resuscitation. It might be used metaphorically after the event to describe something that has brought a person's reputation "back from the dead", but it doesn't really fit OP's situation.

I have edited this to "The kiss of life: the definite article is required. Your answer is then accurate.

Neither of the quotes that you added are examples of when a disreputable person A publicly rebukes person B and as a result we sympathize more with person B.

The question is "Is there an opposite of "kiss of death"?" - the answer is "Yes, it is "the kiss of life". -- The question exemplifies "kiss of death" - the examples I added exemplify [the figurative] "the kiss of life".
